# How Array.reduce put functions as parameters in function composition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, composition

Can somebody explain to me how Array.reduce can put functions as arguments in function composition like this:

```
const  composeB  = (f, g) =>  x  =>  f(g(x))

const  add = a => b => a  +  b
const  add5 = add(5)
const  double = a => a * 2

const add5ThenDouble  = [double, add5].reduce(composeB)

console.log(add5ThenDouble(6)); // 22
```

So, according to my knowledge (which is not enough) of reduce function is that Array.reduce iterate through an array like this - it takes each of array values and puts them through callback function with another argument (lets call it accumulator). The next array value will undergo the same callback function, but with (eventually) changed accumulator value.

What confuses me in code example above is:

1) Array is list of functions [double, add5].

2) In first iteration, composeB will receive arguments: f=accumulator (empty value), g=double(function). ComposeB should return emptyvalue(double(6)) (or maybe not??)

I know that I am missing something, but can someone explain me what?

Comment: The example would be better if they had used `[double, add5].reduce(compose, identity)`

Comment: The author does that later in the article.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for reduce says that the first argument is

> A function to execute on each element in the array (except for the first, if no initialValue is supplied).

So in this case, you have not supplied an `initialValue` and so `compose` is only called once (with arguments `double` and `add5`).

Comment: `double` is not a keyword in JavaScript. At least not any more. Certainly not if the code is using ES6 arrow functions :-)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I just saw the blue word in the question

Answer (score -1):

```js
var inc = (x) => ++x, // increment +1
    x2 = (x) => x*2, // multiply by 2
    sq = (x) => x*x; // square

var compose = (f,g) => (_) => g(f(_));

var f1 = [ sq, inc, inc ].reduce(compose, (_) => _); 
f1(10); // 102

var f2 = [ inc, sq, inc ].reduce(compose, (_) => _); 
f2(10); // 122
```

See the code above, notice:

- identity function `(_) => _` as default value (second argument) for `reduce`
- compose will NOT return a number, it will return a FUNCTION that is a composition of all the functions that were passed in before... So - only when you CALL the (say) `f1`, only then the functions will be executed.
- we are putting all the functions from list `[a,b,c,d,e]` into a chain of `e,d,c,b,a` (reverse order!) and then execute as `e(d(c(b(a(10)))))` getting the order we actually wanted.
- `(f,g) => (_) => g(f(_))` <-- function arguments are actually reversed when calling them. Longer version: `function compose (f, g) { return function (z) { return g(f(z)); }; }`

---

*p.s.: i use `var` because i can ;)*

Comment: notice the identity function as default value for `reduce`. If you have more questions - ask in comments to this answer, i will gladly answer.

Comment: It's not self explanatory to me, sorry. I changed your example (I added a counter and a few console logs), so I can ask you clear and straight questions. So, here it is: https://pastebin.com/SEmK7Epp. When f1 is itterated for the first time compose receives f(accumulator)=identity function, g=sq, x=10? But compose will return number value 100, how come that the next accumulator value is the next function from the list? And if you check the counter value, the first function is passed to compose under the last counter value (but it is clear from the final result that it is executed first)???

Comment: compose will NOT return a number 100, it will return a FUNCTION that is a composition of all the functions that were passed in before... you see - only when you CALL the (say) `f1`,  only then the functions will be executed. So we are putting all the functions from list `[a,b,c,d,e]` into a chain of `e,d,c,b,a` (reverse order) and then execute as `e(d(c(b(a(10)))))` getting the order we actually wanted.

Comment: `(f,g) => (_) => g(f(_))`  <-- you see that arguments are actually reversed when calling them. Longer version: `function compose (f, g) { return function (z) { return g(f(z)); }; }`

Comment: Man, thank you, thank you, thank you... I finally understood it after headbanging for 3 days. Cheers!!