# Javascript Compose order of execution of functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

```
const compose = (f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args));
const bigTask  = (...fns) => fns.reduce(compose);
bigTask(
  task1,
  task2,
  task3,
  task4
)(user, {data:'data'})
```

my understanding is the function  reduce first picks task1 and task2 and then passes them to compose. The result of the above and task3 is picked as the next arguments to the compose function.
The individual tasks: task1, task2... are not dependent on each other so it's not a recursive functions. So the execution order for me should be task1, task2, task3 and then task4.

Instead the actual execution order is task4, task3, task2, task1. Why!!! bangs own head in frustation!!!!
I also understand that f(g(x)) will execute g(x) first and then f(). But can somebody please explain me why task4 is executed first. I see there is giant gap between my understanding of compose and  "how it actually works"

Comment: Well, it seems you're constructing something like `bigTask(x) = task1(task2(task3(task4(x))))`, so it would make sense for `task4` to be the first.

Comment: _“I also understand that `f(g(x))` will execute `g(x)` first and then `f()`”_ — Exactly; so why are you expecting `task1` to be executed before `task2`?

Comment: @user4642212 i am thinking like task 2 executes then task1 and then task3 and then task 4.

Comment: Related: [How Array.reduce put functions as parameters in function composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59636303/4642212).

Comment: @Aioros can you explain more... I am just stuck.

Comment: @cjava Hint: the first argument of a `reduce` method is the _aggregator_, the second one is the next array element. What if you execute the above code by hand? Once `f` is equivalent to `(...args) => task1(task2(...args))` and `g` is `task3`, what will the result in `compose` look like? Like `(...args) => task1(task2(task3(...args)))` or like `(...args) => task3(task1(task2(...args)))`?

Comment: Use `reduceRight` instead of `reduce` .

Comment: @JonasWilms Or simply flip the functions to `g(f(...args))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main confusion stems from bad variable names, namely `f` and`g`, it might get easier to understand if we write:

```
 const compose = (prev, curr) => (...args) => prev(curr(...args));
```

On every iteration, a function gets created, whereas `prev` points to the function created in the previous iteration:

```
 // 1
 task1
 // 2 (two)
 (...args) => task1(task2(...args))
 // 3 (three)
 (...args) => two(task3(...args))
 // 4 (four)
 (...args) => three(task4(...args))
 // unfolded
 (...args) => task1(task2(task3(task4(...args)))
```

As suggested already there are three possible solutions:

(1) swap `curr` and `prev` so that `curr` gets called first.

(2) Use `reduceRight` instead of `reduce`

(3) Get rid of all the unneccessary closures and do:

```
 const bigTask = (...fns) => arg => fns.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), arg);
```

Comment: so can I say that here reduce creates a function chain and the chain ordering is according to compose function. and if the compose func was something (f, g) => (...args) => f(...args) + g(...args); then obviously there is not question of order of function

Comment: @cjava With function composition and a fold (aka reduce) you create a deferred data structure like `x => f(g(h(i(j(x))))))`. If you have another function `k` and apply `compose(x => f(g(h(i(j(x)))))), k)` it yields `x => f(g(h(i(j(k(x)))))))`. For `compose` it doesn't matter if you pass a single `k` function or an entire composition `x => f(g(h(i(j(x))))))`, because a composed function acts exactly the same as a single function.

Answer (score 2):

Call fns.reduce(compose); mean something like this

```js
[task1, task2, task3, task4].reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return accumulator(currentValue())
})

// first step
var s1 = function() {task1(task2())}
// second step
var s2 = function() {s1(task3())}
// third step
var s3 = function() {s2(task4())}

s3()->s2(task4)->s1(task3(task4))->task1(task2(task3(task4())))
```